# select under condition in sql

Tags: sql-server, select, case

dears i am writing sql select statement :

```
SELECT 
  CourtCode,
 CourtName+ ' '+ CourtType AS Court 
from  table
```

CourtType is nullable int column

i want when  column `CourtType=null` my select return 'Court'

Comment: this question needs some serious rewording as i can't understand what you are asking at all

Comment: it looks like they want a CASE statement for one of the values selected but I am not positive but the question needs to be cleared up.

Comment: SELECT Diw_Tb_Court.Fd_CourtCode,Diw_Tb_Court.Fd_CourtName + ' '+ Diw_Tb_CourtType.Fd_CourtType AS Court from  table one inner join table to etc.....  this my querey  i want to get court even  Diw_Tb_CourtType.Fd_CourtType =null in sql when   Diw_Tb_CourtType.Fd_CourtType= null result of query  court= null no i donnot need that i want if Diw_Tb_CourtType.Fd_CourtType<> null do the concatination if Diw_Tb_CourtType.Fd_CourtType==null  there is no need of concate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a job for [`ISNULL()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [`COALESCE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
SELECT 
  Diw_Tb_Court.Fd_CourtCode,
  COALESCE(Diw_Tb_Court.Fd_CourtName + ' ', '')
  + COALESCE(Diw_Tb_CourtType.Fd_CourtType, '') AS Court 
FROM …
```

Answer (score 1):

The way this question is written it's difficult to understand your needs but if I were to guess, I think you just need a left outer join and a CASE statement.  The left outer join ensure that rows from the Diw_Tb_Court table are returned even if there isn't a matching row in the Diw_tb_CourtType table.  The CASE statement lets you interrogate whether the Diw_Tb_courtType join happened and if so, appends it's name to your "name" column.

```
SELECT
   c.Fd_CourtCode,
   name = c.Fd_CourtName + 
      CASE WHEN ct.Fd_CourtType is not null THEN ' ' + ct.Fd_CourtType ELSE '' END
FROM
   Diw_Tb_Court c 
   left outer join Diw_Tb_CourtType ct on ct.id = c.courtType
```